# How to send message or establish 2 way communication between two XUL Overlay Firefox extensions/add-ons

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, xul

I have an [**XUL Overlay** Firefox extension](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Overlay_Extensions), I need to develop a dummy **XUL** extension that establishes connection with the original extension and sends a set of parameters (message) to the original extension. In short, I have to trigger my original extension with my dummy extension.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest way to do this is to have the original extension listening for a [custom event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent) on the base browser window.  The dummy extension can then [create and dispatch the event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events) with whatever custom data is desired.

Creating and dispatching the event from the dummy:

```
function sendDataToMainExtension(data) {

    if (typeof window === "undefined") {
        //If there is no window defined, get the most recent.
        var window=Components.classes["@mozilla.org/appshell/window-mediator;1"]
                           .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIWindowMediator)
                             .getMostRecentWindow("navigator:browser");
    }

    //This assumes that this event is being both sent from 
    //  and received by privileged (main add-on) code.
    var event = new CustomEvent('MyExtensionName-From-Dummy', { 'detail': data });
    window.dispatchEvent(event);
}
```

You may need to take the same steps for making sure the `data` is visible on the receiving end as would be necessary when [firing from privileged code to non-privileged code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent#Firing_from_privileged_code_to_non-privileged_code).

Listening for the event in main:

```
Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm");
const Ci = Components.interfaces;

//Listen for the event on all windows as it is unknown on which one
//  the event will be sent.
function loadIntoWindow(myWindow) {
    myWindow.addEventListener("MyExtensionName-From-Dummy",
                                      receiveMessageFromDummy, false);
}

function unloadFromWindow(myWindow) {
    myWindow.removeEventListener("MyExtensionName-From-Dummy",
                                      receiveMessageFromDummy, false);
}

function forEachOpenWindow(fn) {
    // Apply a function to all open browser windows
    var windows = Services.wm.getEnumerator("navigator:browser");
    let windowCount =0;
    while (windows.hasMoreElements()) {
        windowCount++;
        fn(windows.getNext().QueryInterface(Ci.nsIDOMWindow));
    }
}

function receiveMessageFromDummy(event) {
    var dataFromDummy = event.detail;
    //Do whatever was desired with the data.
}

var WindowListener = {
    onOpenWindow: function(aWindow)
    {
        let domWindow = aWindow.QueryInterface(Ci.nsIInterfaceRequestor)
                               .getInterface(Ci.nsIDOMWindowInternal || Ci.nsIDOMWindow);
        function onWindowLoad()
        {
            domWindow.removeEventListener("load",onWindowLoad);
            if (domWindow.document.documentElement.getAttribute("windowtype") 
                                                              == "navigator:browser") {
                loadIntoWindow(domWindow);
            }
        }
        domWindow.addEventListener("load",onWindowLoad);
    },

    onCloseWindow: function(xulWindow) { },  // Each window has an unload event handler.

    onWindowTitleChange: function(xulWindow, newTitle) { }
};

//Listen for the custom event on all current browser windows.
forEachOpenWindow(loadIntoWindow);
//Listen for the custom event on any new browser window.
Services.wm.addListener(WindowListener);
```

The data sent should be available as [event.detail](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/detail) within the `receiveMessageFromDummy()` function.

The code above provides one way communication. Two way communication is obtained just duplicating the code to communicate in the other direction with a different custom event. In other words, by having the main extension dispatching a different custom event called something like `MyExtensionName-From-Main` and having the dummy extension listening for that event. The code is exactly the same as above, but with the event name changed and the function called being `receiveMessageFromMain()`.

Alternately, you could use [Window.postMessage()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage). Doing so sends a "message" event for which you can listen. However, doing so leads to complications which are easier to avoid by using a custom event (e.g. you have to account for the fact that any code (i.e. some other random extension) could be using this event for their own purpose).

<sup>Note: The code to loop through windows was originally taken from [Converting an old overlay-based Firefox extension into a restartless addon](https://flagfox.wordpress.com/2014/01/19/writing-restartless-addons/) which that author re-wrote as the initial part of [How to convert an overlay extension to restartless](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/How_to_convert_an_overlay_extension_to_restartless) on MDN. It has been modified multiple times from that code. It may have even earlier versions from other sources.</sup>